# Can you use structural search and replace to remove function calls in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I've got some old PHP code I'm refactoring. I'm changing from using old style escaping to using prepared statements. So I'm looking to get rid of stuff like this:

```
$ath_no = mysql_real_escape_string($csvEntry[1]);
```

Changed to:

$ath_no = $csvEntry[1];

I know I could use standard replace, but it wouldn't get rid of the close bracket.

Can I use PhpStorms' structural search and replace for this and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm allows you to use [regular expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html) in [find & replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html#example).

You can this regular expression:

```
mysql_real_escape_string\((.*)\)
```

And the replacement should be:

```
$1
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise you could do that. I'm having a little trouble with that regex, but i'll play with it to get it to work.

Comment: @DavidFindlay, all of the lines you want to replace are in the same structure? Or some of them have more function-calls? `func(func(mysql_real_escape_string(..)))`

Comment: Turned out it was a copy and paste error. For some reason having a space after the regex stopped it work. I do have some other locations though I'll have to work with that have more function calls.

Comment: Well... it's not "for some reason" - it's how regex works. If you have a space in your search-string it will be looking for that space in the document :)

Comment: Yep. That would be the reason. Certainly kept me looking for what was different for a while!